# Log concavity preserved by marginalization? Prékopa–Leindler inequality?

Tags: analysis, inequality, probability-distributions

As a result of
[Prékopa–Leindler inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9kopa%E2%80%93Leindler_inequality#Applications_in_probability_and_statistics)(application in Log-concave distributions), if $f(x, y)$ is log-concave in $(x,y)$, then $f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) \, dy$ is log-concave in $x$. However, I comeup with an counterexample. Let $f(x, y) = \exp(xy-y^2)$.  Clearly $f(x, y)$ is log-concave, but $f(x) =  \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) \, dy =\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp(xy-y^2) dy = \sqrt{\pi} \exp(x^2/4)$ is log-convex.

What's wrong with my example?

Comment: Are you sure that $f$ is log-concave?

Comment: $xy-y^2$ is a concave function, right?

Comment: @fixed Check the Hessian. Alternatively, consider what happens near the origin along two paths: $y=-x$ and $y=x/2.$

Comment: The hessian of $xy-y^2$ is $[[0, 0], [0, -2]]$, which is negative semi-definite, showing that $\log f(x,y) =xy-y^2$ is  concave. Am I right? @Golden_Ratio

Comment: @Brian Borchers

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hessian+xy-y%5E2&wal=header

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! @Golden_Ratio